# zf2 route param like GET array

Tags: zend-framework2

Please anyone can tell me how to implement zf2 route to have a route like this
/filter/value1/value2
 and receive an array like this:

```
filter = [
   value1,
   value2,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly this URL `/filter/value1/value2`, you could define segment route with wildcard constraint:

```php
    'filter' => [
        'type' => \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment::class,
        'options' => [
            'route' => '/filter/:filter',
            'defaults' => [
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                'action' => 'index',
            ],
            'constraints' => [
                'filter' => '(.)+',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

and then in controller you can access the filter variable as array for example like this:

```php
$filter = $this->params('filter', []);
$filter = explode('/', trim($filter, '/'));
```

But if your primary requirement is filter variable as an array and not URL, just use array as query parameter:

```php
    // in controller or template:
    $this->url()->fromRoute('filter', [], [
        'query' => [
            'filter' => [
                'value1',
                'value2',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

This produces url like `?filter[]=value1&filter[]=value2`, but you can access it directly like an array:

```php
    // in controller:
    $filter = $this->params()->fromQuery('filter');
```

Comment: sorry, i need like GET no with get :) i try to use my segment route and a child with wildcard only for filters i receive url like: /ro/computere/laptopuri//sort-pret/dir-desc/page-4/controller:Catalog%5CController%5CCatalog/action:detalii/param1:value1. I do not need maybe as array but to have variate params name who i don't know their name before

Comment: @user3143015: Do not use wildcard route, it is deprecated for security issues (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-wildcard-deprecated) - same as query route (http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-01).

Comment: your first solution was to explode the actual params, but what when i must recreate another url with that param already in url?

Comment: tanks for deprecated info, but i don't know how to use routes with params who i don't know their name because came from database

Comment: As for "recreate another url with that param already in url", I think array_merge should be enough, if I understand right.

Comment: yes, i was made a view helper to explode implode add and remove 'params from param' but i was thinking that maybe was a nicely solution from zend because i don 't think i am only one who need match filter who don't know previously the name:

Comment: I don't know about something like that built-in within ZF.